# Is it appropriate to ask for a Skype meeting instead of traveling for a face-to-face meeting? and how to do it?

Tags: interviewing, resume, united-states

So I was in contact with a CEO of a company in the USA. I'll send him my resume on Linkedin and asked for available positions. I also mentioned that I'll go to states for a month ( as I'm in Canada now). He said that my resume is interesting and directed me to his secretary to set up a face-to-face meeting.
I really like to fly there but first, it would be a costly trip to fly to that state from the place I'll be. Secondly, he did not tell me whether they have any open positions so shall I even go there?
Third, if I decide to ask for Skype, will I look disinterested? and what if there was an opportunity that I could get by a face-2-face meeting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The root issue: you seem to have no idea what he wants to talk to you about. I don't even make a *phone call* with someone without knowing what they want to talk to me about.

So find that out to the best of your ability.

In general, they should pay for travel accommodations, and as a corollary it would stand to reason they have an open position for you if you are worth flying in.

Comment: ... or are willing to create one.  It's not unheard of for a CEO to hire someone *then* create the opening for them.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. I'm not sure whether I'll miss a great position by offering a skype interview or not.. however, even if I fly there, the interview may end with no result as well... just don't know what to do.

Comment: Contact his secretary.  He either didn't notice that you're from out of town, or he did notice and is willing to pay for travel.  Either way, the secretary will know.

Comment: Well, he did not say anything about travel payment. I think its great idea to ask his secretary. However, I'm thinking how I could  ask for a skype meeting rather than a F2F one politely.

Comment: @ambitiouslady you need to ask why he wants to talk to you. you do not fly out to another city to meet someone without knowing why.